# Django Model Save and "Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY"

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model, with two foreignkey filed to one model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   boss = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name = 'the_boss')

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
       if self.pk:
          #do some staff
       super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `boss` field, add in model update. But when model updates (django admin) I have

> Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY
>
> super(MyModel, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)

error. Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details (explicit the `do some staff part`) to be able to understand the problem.

Comment: Why don't you just have one optional `ForeignKey` to the `User` model?  That is why it is giving you the error, because you have two.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `related_name` to the user ForeignKey as well

Comment: the same issue with related_name.

Answer (score 0):

Using `related_name` should work. Either the issue is on the `#do some staff` part or elsewhere like in model migrations.